# Redirect /usr/include/stdio.h to sed

Tags: sed, redirect

I'm really fuzzy on the use of the `sed` streamline editor; all I remember about redirecting files to sed is to use `<` operator somehow. Could anyone explain how to redirect the file  `/usr/include/stdio.h` to `sed`, and break down the commands?

Using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Although historically a "stream editor", modern implementations of `sed` are capable of reading files without redirection i.e. `sed '<some commands>' /usr/include/stdio.h`. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: redirect  `/usr/include/stdio.h....` into `sed`, and then screw with the text in that file a bit. If I sound stupid, please tell me why.

Answer (score 3):

The input redirection operator is `<` so for example

```
$ sed -n '1p' < /usr/include/stdio.h
/* Define ISO C stdio on top of C++ iostreams.
```

However, in spite of the history of its name as a "**s**tream **ed**itor", modern implementations of `sed` can read files by name directly, **without** input redirection

```
$ sed -n '1p' /usr/include/stdio.h
/* Define ISO C stdio on top of C++ iostreams.
```

> **Note**: don't change the contents of the actual `/usr/include/stdio.h` file. Make a local copy if you want to play with it.